# Calling a servlet from a form but the servlet is never invoked

Tags: java, jsp, forms, servlets

I am trying to call a Servlet called AddClass.java using the following line in a jsp

```
<form method="post" name="addClass" action="AddClass.do">
```

The class is in package **web** and the filename is **AddClass.java**

A similar servlet named SeedSearch is called (and everything works fine) from this piece of code in another jsp.

```
<form method="post" name="seedSearch" action="SeedSearch">
```

My web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>sempedia</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SeedSearch</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>web.SeedSearch</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>AddClass</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>web.AddClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SeedSearch</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/SeedSearch</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>AddClass</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/AddClass.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Please help.

Comment: Just to clarify it's the call to AddClass that doesn't work, the call to SeedSearch works fine.

Comment: what are the paths of both jsp files?

Comment: The xml configuration seems to be ok. May be the problem is as @Yony said, a path calling. Try to add to the action of the form: '/AddClass.do'. Or try: action="<c:url value="/AddClass.do"/>".

Comment: Jsp paths are
Project-name > WebContent > jsp > AddClass.jsp

and 

Project-name > WebContent > index.jsp

These are different but I thought the web.xml mappings made that unimportant.

Comment: I added ../ in front of AddClass and it works - thanks Yoni

Comment: But your servlet path has the '/' that means from root. So the speedSearch works because is invoked from the root of the application, and addClass doesn't work because is searching a map from '/WebContent/jsp/'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `web.xml` looks fine, so the problem lies somewhere else.

1. URL is plain wrong. Relative URL's must be extracted from its absolute form based on the current request URL or -if any- the HTML `<base>` tag. Take care: the leading slash takes you to the domain root! This is **not** necessarily the correct solution as others here seem to think, especially not if webapp has a context path.
2. Package/classname in `web.xml` doesn't match actual Servlet class (casesensitive!)
3. Servlet class isn't in the classpath of the running webproject. At least, not at the expected location.
4. Servlet class failed to load/initialize. Read appserver logs for exception/error details.
5. There's actually more in `web.xml`, e.g. another servlet which eats `*.do` and got precedence.
6. You aren't running the webproject with the particular `web.xml` you think you are. Doubleverify, rebuild, redeploy and restart.

Comment: Thanks very useful as a general checklist, I am sure someone will find that list useful in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

There's no leading '/' in your call to SeedSearch.

Comment: Hi Steve, actually the same error occurs without the / - I added that in desperation hoping it might change things. I have removed it, as that is the way the code is.

Comment: It would only return 404 if there's a context.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are mapping "*.do" in somewhere else (struts may be?) and your servlet is never called.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I just added the .do to try something different and I have not used struts on this machine ever.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK20O.png)

2 servlets: KK is default or normal way; LL is in a custom package. 
inside web.xml, LL must have fully qualified name **not only** for class, **but also** for servlet name.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBFOC.png)

calling each servlet from html is the same for both: 
     or 

no need of any qualification